# Empirical Bayesian kriging - does data need to be normal?

Tags: interpolation, kriging, distribution

With empirical Bayesian kriging (ebk), does the data need to be normally distributed?

If I apply a normal score transformation, my data is still not normal. Is ebk kriging thus an invalid interpolation technique for my data, or can I get around this?